# Trovan LID-573ISO Pocket Reader via Javascript's Web Bluetooth

Tags: javascript, bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

I hope someone can help me with my email.

I'm trying to develop a website that interacts with a Trovan LID-573ISO Pocket Reader via [Web Bluetooth](https://web.dev/bluetooth/). I can connect to the Pocket Reader via Bluetooth, but when I can the RFID tag, the Pocket Reader successfully reads the tag, but it's not sending the ID back via Web BlueTooth. If I pair the portable reader with my iPhone and have Notes app open and scan the tag, the tag successfully shows up in the Notes app. But I can't get this to work via the [Web Bluetooth](https://web.dev/bluetooth/) code.

Here's the code below. I'm testing it on Google Chrome on my Windows 10 machine.

```
function connect () {
   navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({ 
      acceptAllDevices: true})
   
   .then(device => device.gatt.connect())

   .then(server => {
      return server.getPrimaryService('9cae0f23-579e-4fde-87a9-bf39e664de8c');
   })

   .then(service => {
      return service.getCharacteristic('200f8d51-2a33-4ef3-9e60-2d9c2c10adca');
   })           

   .then(characteristic => {      
      return characteristic.startNotifications(); 
   })

   .then(characteristic => {
      characteristic.addEventListener('characteristicvaluechanged', handleCharacteristicValueChanged);
      log('characteristicvaluechanged started');
   })
   
   .catch(error => { 
      var ss = error;
      console.log(error); });
}

function handleCharacteristicValueChanged(event) {
   log('In handleCharacteristicValueChanged')
   var value = event.target.value;
   log('Received ' + value);      
   log('Received ' + event.target);  
}
```

When I run the page, I can connect to the device via BlueTooth, but the handleCharacteristicValueChanged code is fired once after I connect to the device, and never fired again.

These are the Services on the device I can see.

[Services](https://awss3buckettutorial.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/top.png)
[And More Services](https://awss3buckettutorial.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/top2.png)

What I need is when the reader reads a chip, it sends the ID back via BlueTooth.

I need some help! :(

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem in windows10，But under mac, I can stay connected and get data，[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtPEg.jpg)

I don't know the reason

```js
function bluetoothConnect() {
        console.log('Requesting Bluetooth Device...');
        navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
            filters: [{ services: ['0000ff00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb']}]
        }).then(device => {
            console.log('device')
            return device.gatt.connect();
        }).then(server => {
            return server.getPrimaryService('0000ff00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb')
        }).then(service => {
            console.log('service')
            return service.getCharacteristic('0000ff01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb')
        }).then(characteristics => {
            console.log('characteristics')
            myCharacteristic = characteristics
            myCharacteristic.addEventListener('characteristicvaluechanged', test)
            return myCharacteristic.startNotifications()
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }
```